# Which make BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 error occur in my ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, docker

I'm newbie using Ubuntu 14.04 and I get BIDSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 error when I tried to install docker. Error message is

> `W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The
>   following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu
>   Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>`

I followed instructions from docker doc and did this

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://­ha.pool.sks-keyserver­s.net:80\
     --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C07­0ADBF76221572C52609D
$ echo "deb https://­apt.dockerproject.org­/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/­sources.list.d/­docker.list
```

If I remember correctly, after I entered it, I installed docker. And then, I installed this

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(­uname -r) linux-image-extra-vi­rtual
```

but while downloading, I forced close the terminal. After these steps, I start get BADSIG error when I use apt-get update. Is there any steps I've done wrong that lead to BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 error.

For error, I used the following steps and it looks fine now. I tried to solve by removing docker first.And `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192` and

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get clean
# cd /var/lib/apt
# mv lists lists.old
# mkdir -p lists/partial
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
```

but I still get BADSIG error. Then, I tried this and it solve my error but I don't know why.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/­* -vf
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/­partials/* -vf
```

and from "Software & Updates", selected server to "Other/Select Best" and
sudo apt-get update.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get -f install` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Also, please show the full output you get with this error.

Comment: @Paranoid Panda , my problem is now clear with the command at bottom of my post. What I want to know is which command  lead to such error while I was installing docker. As I'm  trying to install docker now, I don't want to face that error again.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please just run `sudo apt-get update` and then [edit] your question and paste in the output. I just want to see the error in its entirety because it would normally show more about the issue.

Comment: I've added my error message